# Create outer div if counter is divisible by 4

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I have a problem looping my html tags. My goal is to enclose every 4 div with class "item" inside the class of "item-wrap". So far here's my code:

$speakers will return 8 rows so "item-wrap" class will be display twice with 4 "item" class inside

```
<?php
            $speaker_ctr = 0;
            if(count($speakers) > 0){
            ?>
            <div class="item-wrap">
                <?php foreach($speakers as $speaker){ ?>
                <div class="item"> <img class="lazy" data-lazy-src="<?php echo $speaker['imagepath']; ?>" />
                    <h5 class="txt-18 bold-font text-uppercase no-mbt mt-20"><?php echo $speaker['name']; ?></h3>
                    <p class="no-mn"><?php echo $speaker['position']; ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $speaker['url']; ?>" target="_blank" class="txt-14 theme no-mn"><?php echo $speaker['company']; ?></a>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php
                $speaker_ctr++;
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with -

```
        $speaker_ctr = 0;
        if(count($speakers) > 0){
        ?>
        <div class="item-wrap">
            <?php 
            foreach($speakers as $speaker){ 
            $speaker_ctr++; // increment
            ?>
            <div class="item"> <img class="lazy" data-lazy-src="<?php echo $speaker['imagepath']; ?>" />
                <h5 class="txt-18 bold-font text-uppercase no-mbt mt-20"><?php echo $speaker['name']; ?></h3>
                <p class="no-mn"><?php echo $speaker['position']; ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo $speaker['url']; ?>" target="_blank" class="txt-14 theme no-mn"><?php echo $speaker['company']; ?></a>
            </div>
            <?php 
              // print if divisible by 4
              // every 4th element
              if($speaker_ctr%4 == 0 && $speaker_ctr != count($speakers)) {
                echo "</div><div class='item-wrap'>";
              }
            } 
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
```

Comment: Doing this can lead to an open empty row if the last item is divisible by 4.  You should check at the start of the foreach to open a new row and at the end of the foreach to close the row.

Comment: @Styphon Ahh!! Missed that one!!

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:-

```
<?php
if(count($speakers) > 0){

    for($i=0;$i<=count($speakers);$i++){
        if($i%4==0){
            echo '<div class="item-wrap">';
        }
    ?>
        <div class="item"> <img class="lazy" data-lazy-src="<?php echo $speakers[$i]['imagepath']; ?>" />
            <h5 class="txt-18 bold-font text-uppercase no-mbt mt-20"><?php echo $speakers[$i]['name']; ?></h3>
            <p class="no-mn"><?php echo $speakers[$i]['position']; ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo $speakers[$i]['url']; ?>" target="_blank" class="txt-14 theme no-mn"><?php echo $speakers[$i]['company']; ?></a>
        </div>

    <?php
        if($i%4==0){
            echo '</div>';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the or in your if statements, if `$i = 0` then `$i % 4 == 0` will be true.

Comment: @Styphon: Yes. You are correct. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @SydneyLoteria: Are you facing any problem in this answer?